# How to factorize values that include modular arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have an equation:

$b*(x*rinv*s*b\mod n) - (x*b)$

In which i need to isolate `x` but when i do:

$ x*(rinv*s*b \mod n) - b)$

The results are different, Why?

Here are the values:

```
x = 9425462603919758403509431170377741597727182287022881396228286868666458414738
b = 100906376405775661990562963813068351310177981465009640700224287315820973458674
a = 44286717587595936018074743368265679694432636709170485099126082338272318217947
n =115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494337
```

How can i factor this correctly, I am really confused with modulo right now.

Comment: What is your order of operation between the $*$ and $\bmod$ in $(x*rinv*s*b\mod n)$?

Comment: Please fix the unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: Are both answers the same modulo n?

Comment: Generally $\ \begin{align}&\color{#c00}b(xa \bmod n)-bx\\
\not\equiv &\ \ x(a  \bmod n\, -\, b)\end{align} \pmod{\!n},\ $ but it is true if you delete $\,\color{#c00}b,\,$ by the congruence sum and product rules in the linked dupe.